# bluetooth serial COM connection. There seems to be no API in BlueSoleil for RFCOMM servers

Tags: c#, bluetooth, rfcomm, 32feet

in my application im want to connect to electronic device (it is not a phone or .... !) and get a packet from it.
i need to reed data from serial COM port.
i used the code below for connection:

```
        private void bSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listener = new BluetoothListener(BluetoothService.SerialPort);
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginAcceptBluetoothClient(this.BluetoothListenerAcceptClientCallback, listener);
    }
    void BluetoothListenerAcceptClientCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var listener = (BluetoothListener)result.AsyncState;
        listener.BeginAcceptBluetoothClient(this.BluetoothListenerAcceptClientCallback, listener);
        BluetoothClient client = listener.EndAcceptBluetoothClient(result);
        client.Close();
    }
```

Note: when i can recieve data from serial port when i manually connect to device's bluetooth! but programically by using 32feet i recieve this error:
"There seems to be no API in BlueSoleil for RFCOMM servers."
IN LINE:

```
There seems to be no API in BlueSoleil for RFCOMM servers.
```

what is wrong, what can i do??!!

Comment: come on guys! any idea?

Comment: where did you get in the end? were you sucessful?

Comment: Also. It's normal to connect to a third-party device and read and write data from it -- it is _not_ necessary to run as a server just to receive data.

Answer (score 0):

There is (?was) no support in BlueSoleil SDK for being a server, thus 32feet.NET can't support server/listener.

https://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BlueSoleil